# TextView and EditText looks messy

Tags: android, xml, android-edittext

I have created a login page for an App I am creating. I am in the process now of making the UI look decent. In my login page (and other pages where I need to input data) if the phone is vertical the EditText boxes won't snap to the screen to view what is being typed. Whereas if the phone is Horizontal it does?

Do any of you have any idea why this may be happening?

Here is the XML code if it helps:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:background="@color/background"
    android:padding="30dip">

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_gravity="center">
        <TableLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:gravity="center"
            android:stretchColumns="*">
            <EditText android:id="@+id/username" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:background="@android:drawable/editbox_background" />
            <EditText android:id="@+id/password" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:password="true" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@android:drawable/editbox_background"
                android:inputType="text" />
            <TableRow>
                <Button android:id="@+id/submit_button" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="@string/login_label" />
                <Button android:id="@+id/back_button" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="@string/back_label" />
            </TableRow>

            <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginBottom="25dip"
                android:gravity="center" android:id="@+id/txtServerStatus" />
        </TableLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use

```
android:SingleLine="true".
```

Comment: I don't have any snaps. Basically, say you are going to send a email, you click on the email body field and that whole box will appear above the keyboard on the screen (this is what happens when my app is Horizontal. Whereas, if the app is vertical the textbox wont take up the rest of the space above the keyboard, it just kinda stays hidden behind the keyboard panel and you cant view what you typing. I can mock a image up on paint if you like? (:

Comment: I checked your code it is not showing the keyboard in landscape mode in emulator but it is working fine over device. I checked it in Samsung Galaxy S.

Comment: That's ok. When you use the code and select the username input box, the whole inputbox takes up the remainder of the screen when it is landscape. So the bottom half will be keyboard and top half will be where you enter the data. Whereas when the phone is vertical, when you select the inputbox it wont take up the space on the screen like it does in landscape.

Comment: ohh that's the device property you can't do anything in that but you can fix your orientation to portrait mode of your activity using the property android:screenOrientation = "portrait" you can use it for whole app then set it in application tag or for single activity then set it on activity tag.....Hope it helps you...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure i'm following you here. But if you mean that your TextEdit "boxes" are left empty, it's because Android calls the onCreate method when you flip the screen orientation.
Therefore you need to save the text in the textfields.

If might consider removing the flipping. You can do that in the Manifest under application:

```
<application
android:screenOrientation="portrait"
>
```